# (Ubuntu 20.04) Unable to start GUI after reboot, ACPI errors

Tags: boot, 20.04, bios, acpi, busybox

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 (host OS, not a VM) and spontaneously started getting errors while using Obsidian, which I closed but failed to reopen. Then, I rebooted my computer, but now the GUI doesn't start and instead I see:

```
[    0.099563] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by bios
[    0.166329] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCIO.RP09.PXSX], AE_ALREADY_EXIST (20210730/dswload2-326)
[    0.166338] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
[    0.166346] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCIO.RP21.PXSX], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
[    0.166350] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
[    2.233426]

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.4) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _
```

What caused this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Uhhhhhh, never mind, I just solved this with fsck.

Comment: If you solved it yourself, you should instead answer your own question, and in 2 days, you can also accept it. In the answer, you could also provide the exact `fsck` command you ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve it, I ran `exit`, got a message indicating the corrupted partition, ran `fsck $PARTITION_PATH$ -y`, and then rebooted the computer. The GUI started normally.